# Force update of QTListWidget to add/remove elements

Tags: qt, qt5, redraw

I'm attempting to wrap a GUI around an existing management console app. The main function is to search for network devices, which is given a timeout and is essentially a blocking call until the timeout has expired (using sleep to do the blocking). In this example the call is `this->Manager->Search(...)`.

My issue is that I want the QListWidget to display "Searching..." while the search is taking place, and then update with the results at the completion of the search. My on-click code for the `Search` button is as follows:

```
void ManagerGUI::on_searchButton_clicked()
{
  ui->IPList->clear();
  new QListWidgetItem(tr("Searching..."), ui->IPList);
  ui->IPList->repaint();
  this->Manager->Search(static_cast<unsigned int>(this->ui->searchTime->value()*1000.0));
  ui->IPList->clear();
  if(this->Manager->GetNumInList() != 0)
    this->displayFoundInList(this->Manager->GetFoundList());
  else
    new QListWidgetItem(tr("No Eyes Found"), ui->IPList);
  ui->IPList->repaint();
}
```

When I hit the button, the `QListWidget` `IPList` does not update until after the timeout has taken place (and I assume until after this callback has terminated). Does anyone have any suggestions? I was under the impression that calling `ui->IPList->repaint()` would cause an immediate redraw of the list.

Additional info:

- QT Version 5.1.0 32-Bit
- Compiled using VS2012
- Running on Win7 Pro 64-bit (but to be ported to OSX and Linux, so nothing win-specific please)

Comment: If you block in this->Manager->Search you should run in another thread...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You don't need to call repaint directly.

2) You should do your search asynchronously. It is big topic - you should learn basics of Qt first.

Start with signals and slots and then learn about QThread or QtConcurrent. Then implement a class that will do searching and send necessary signals: first signal on search start, second signal - on search stop. Then connect slots to this signals and work with your list view insine this slots.

Problem is that your "Search manager" blocks Qt's event loop. Thats why listview does not repainted.

Comment: Vote up. Since this probably will be a single call the quickest implementation would be Qt::Concurrent. The quick overview would be: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/thread-basics.html

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, this makes everything much clearer, although it's not the answer I was hoping for. I was hoping the repaint occurred in a different thread-space to the event callback executions, but clearly I was hoping to be lazier than was possible.

The Manager code already uses Boost to do all my network I/O, so I can spawn a worker thread down there and register a callback up to the Q layer. That way other users of my manager library would have the option of an asynchronous call as-well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a signal slot system because your search is blocking. Ideally you should do the search in a new thread. However you can cheat with a processEvents()

```
void ManagerGUI::on_searchButton_clicked()
{
  ui->IPList->clear();
  new QListWidgetItem(tr("Searching..."), ui->IPList);
  emit signalStartSearch();
}

void ManageGUI::slotStartSearch()
{
  // Process any outstanding events (such as repainting)
  QCoreApplication::processEvents();
  this->Manager->Search(static_cast<unsigned int>(this->ui->searchTime->value()*1000.0));
  emit signalSearchCompleted();
}

void ManagerGUI::slotSeachCompleted()
{
  ui->IPList->clear();
  if(this->Manager->GetNumInList() != 0) {
    ui->IPList->setUpdatesEnabled(false);
    this->displayFoundInList(this->Manager->GetFoundList());
    ui->IPList->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
  } else {
    new QListWidgetItem(tr("No Eyes Found"), ui->IPList);
  }
}
```

Ideally you would want the `Manager->Search` to emit the signal and then use `QtConcurrent::run` to do the search in another thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response Phil. I love the workaround, but for this application I really need to bite the bullet and do a proper thread-based implementation of the manager class. Really interesting response tho, I clearly have a lot more to learn about the signalling capabilities of Qt.